# is it possible to insert node.js scrips into php code?

Tags: php, node.js

I googled it but I found a lot stuff about PHP in `node.js`, but I need it the other way round. Have you any sources where I could find an answer ?

Edit: I have a Website based on php, and I need functions reading something from mongodb. Its a partner Projekt and my part is the database, Im n node.js developer so it would be easier for me to write the query functions in node.js. So my question is this possible ?

So this is my php part where I call my node.js script :

```
<?php
 $player = 23534770;
 $mate = 23171708;
 $mode = "NORMAL";
    echo "Start \n";
    passthru('/usr/bin/env node getChampions.js ' . $player . '#' . $mate . '#' . $mode);
//here should be something like : echo $data;
?>
```

And my script just have one Variable , example var data. Yeah and I try want to catch the var ofc to use it in php.

This what i tried:

```
<?php
    echo "Start \n";
    ob_start(passthru('/usr/bin/env node getAll.js '));

    $data = json_decode(ob_get_clean());
    echo "Data : " . $data;
?>
```

Data is still empty, I also tried to out the passthru into the ob_get_clean() function but well, didnt work. $data is empty and I know my script started.

Comment: Please describe a use case, and an example of what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it via a socket. There is a library called Dnode. It makes your script available to other languages via a socket.

Another way is to call nodejs directly via OS execution.
For more info see this document:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing different things. What you found is probably, PHP code that generates HTML pages that have JavaScript code embedded.

NodeJs on the other hand, is only an execution environment to run JavaScript code locally without using a browser (and some other extensions).

You could use NodeJs on your server to generate HTML pages similar which is similar to what you usually do with PHP.